# PowerShell forms | Move label based on check box signed

Tags: powershell

Afternoon,

I'm building a report generator script and, whilst I'm sure the awesomeness of my plans will be overlooked by the Service Desk, I'm still keen to do something pretty snazzy with this.

Basically I have a form populated with different AD / Exchange attributes that when checked, will go off and query AD then dump the results into a CSV.

The form itself is fine but what I'm trying to do is, based on an attributes being ticked, an image displays that resembles the CSV in Excel. If for instance you click Username, an image appears with SamAccountName in what would be column A. When you click Name, an image appears next to SamAccountName with Name in column B. It's basically a visual demo of what you're going to see when you run the report.

What I'm struggling to do though is move the images around based on them being ticked. So if SamAccountName isn't ticked, then move Name to the left so it would appear in column A.
I've managed to get the form to behave in a manner that says SamAccountName first, then Name, then x, y, z in that order, but I just can't figure out how to get the form to check if a box is ticked and move an image left accordingly.

Here's a cut down version of the form.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()


$ADREPORT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ADREPORT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 270,175 )
$ADREPORT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 700,400 )
$ADREPORT.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$ADREPORT.BackColor     = "Lavender"
$ADREPORT.Font          = "Calibri, 8.5"

# This creates a label for the header
$ADHEADER               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADHEADER.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 30,20 )
$ADHEADER.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 180,20 )
$ADHEADER.Font          = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold )
$ADHEADER.Text          = "Choose your attributes"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $ADHEADER )


# This creates a label for the header
$ADTEXT                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADTEXT.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 30,50 )
$ADTEXT.Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 300,40 )
$ADTEXT.Text            = "From the list below, select as many attributes as you like to generate a CSV report:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $ADTEXT )



#This creates a label for running the report on Active Directory Users
$OBJUSERTXT             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJUSERTXT.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,100 )
$OBJUSERTXT.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJUSERTXT.Text        = "USERS:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJUSERTXT ) 

#This creates the checkbox for running the report on Active Directory Users - It's checked by default
$OBJUSERBOX             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJUSERBOX.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,98 )
$OBJUSERBOX.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJUSERBOX.TabIndex    = 0
$OBJUSERBOX.Checked     = $TRUE
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJUSERBOX )


# SamAccountName label
$OBJAD01TXT             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJAD01TXT.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,120 )
$OBJAD01TXT.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJAD01TXT.Text        = "Username:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJAD01TXT ) 

# SamAccountName checkbox
$OBJAD01BOX             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJAD01BOX.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,118 )
$OBJAD01BOX.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJAD01BOX.TabIndex    = 1
$OBJAD01BOX.Checked     = $TRUE
$OBJAD01BOX.Name        = "SamAccountName"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJAD01BOX )

# SamAccountName Image
$IMGAD01                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$IMGAD01.Image          = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile( "$env:Temp\FormSamAccountName.PNG" )
$IMGAD01.Size           = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 48,62 )
$IMGAD01.Location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 319,100 )
$ADREPORT.controls.add( $IMGAD01 )


# Full Name label
$OBJAD02TXT             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJAD02TXT.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,140 )
$OBJAD02TXT.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJAD02TXT.Text        = "Full name:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJAD02TXT )

# Full Name checkbox
$OBJAD02BOX             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$OBJAD02BOX.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,138 )
$OBJAD02BOX.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJAD02BOX.TabIndex    = 2
$OBJAD02BOX.Name        = "Name"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJAD02BOX )

# Full Name Image
$IMGAD02                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$IMGAD02.Image          = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile( "$env:Temp\FormName.PNG" ) 
$IMGAD02.Size           = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 48,62 )
$IMGAD02.Location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 368,100 )
$IMGAD02.Visible        = $FALSE
$ADREPORT.controls.add( $IMGAD02 )



# brings up the SamAccount image when the Username is ticked
$OBJAD01BOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( {
IF ( $OBJAD01BOX.Checked -eq $TRUE )
 { $IMGAD01.Visible = $TRUE } } )


# Removes the SamAccount image when the username is unticked
$OBJAD01BOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( {
IF ( $OBJAD01BOX.Checked -eq $FALSE )
 { $IMGAD01.Visible = $FALSE } } )


# Enables the Name image when the name is ticked. 
$OBJAD02BOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( {
IF ( $OBJAD02BOX.Checked )
 { $IMGAD02.Visible = $TRUE } } )

# Removes the Name image when Name is unchecked.
$OBJAD02BOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( {
IF ( $OBJAD02BOX.Checked -eq $FALSE )
 { $IMGAD02.Visible = $FALSE } } )


# Launch the checkbox form.
$ADREPORT.Add_Shown( { $ADREPORT.Activate() } )
[void] $ADREPORT.ShowDialog()


# If the user checkbox is ticked, create a new variable, then assign the name 
# (AD attribute) of any such check box ticked to this new variable
IF ( $OBJUSERBOX.Checked )
 { $ADVARIABLES = @()
   Get-Variable -Name OBJAD* | ?{ $_.Value.Checkstate -eq 1  } | %{ $ADVARIABLES += $_.Value.Name }

Write-Host "Performing a search of all users on Active Directory. This part can take a minute or so" -f Green ; ""

# Create an empty variable, then perform an AD search of variables selected in the form
$USERS = @()
$USERS += Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property $ADVARIABLES | select $ADVARIABLES | sort Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, the joys of doing a ton of awesome little things that nobody will ever notice or appreciate lol.

There's probably a bunch of ways of doing it, not sure what the tidiest way would be. My approach would be to index the Labels and dynamically set and show them as required.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$IMAGEBOXES = @()
$CHECKBOXES = @()

$ADREPORT               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ADREPORT.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 270,175 )
$ADREPORT.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 700,400 )
$ADREPORT.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$ADREPORT.BackColor     = "Lavender"
$ADREPORT.Font          = "Calibri, 8.5"

# This creates a label for the header
$ADHEADER               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADHEADER.Location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 30,20 )
$ADHEADER.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 180,20 )
$ADHEADER.Font          = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold )
$ADHEADER.Text          = "Choose your attributes"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $ADHEADER )


# This creates a label for the header
$ADTEXT                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ADTEXT.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 30,50 )
$ADTEXT.Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 300,40 )
$ADTEXT.Text            = "From the list below, select as many attributes as you like to generate a CSV report:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $ADTEXT )



#This creates a label for running the report on Active Directory Users
$OBJUSERTXT             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJUSERTXT.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,100 )
$OBJUSERTXT.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJUSERTXT.Text        = "USERS:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJUSERTXT ) 

#This creates the checkbox for running the report on Active Directory Users - It's checked by default
$OBJUSERBOX             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJUSERBOX.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,98 )
$OBJUSERBOX.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJUSERBOX.TabIndex    = 0
$OBJUSERBOX.Checked     = $TRUE
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJUSERBOX )


# SamAccountName label
$OBJAD01TXT             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJAD01TXT.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,120 )
$OBJAD01TXT.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJAD01TXT.Text        = "Username:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJAD01TXT ) 

# SamAccountName checkbox
$OBJAD01BOX             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$OBJAD01BOX.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,118 )
$OBJAD01BOX.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJAD01BOX.TabIndex    = 1
$OBJAD01BOX.Checked     = $TRUE
$OBJAD01BOX.Name        = "SamAccountName"
$OBJAD01BOX.Tag         = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile( "$env:Temp\FormSamAccountName.PNG" )
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJAD01BOX )
$CHECKBOXES += $OBJAD01BOX


# Full Name label
$OBJAD02TXT             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$OBJAD02TXT.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,140 )
$OBJAD02TXT.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 )
$OBJAD02TXT.Text        = "Full name:"
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJAD02TXT )

# Full Name checkbox
$OBJAD02BOX             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
$OBJAD02BOX.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,138 )
$OBJAD02BOX.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$OBJAD02BOX.TabIndex    = 2
$OBJAD02BOX.Name        = "Name"
$OBJAD02BOX.Tag         = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile( "$env:Temp\FormName.PNG" )
$ADREPORT.Controls.Add( $OBJAD02BOX )
$CHECKBOXES += $OBJAD02BOX

# Image 1
$IMGAD01                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$IMGAD01.Size           = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 48,62 )
$IMGAD01.Location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 319,100 )
$ADREPORT.controls.add( $IMGAD01 )
$IMAGEBOXES += $IMGAD01

# Image 2
$IMGAD02                = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$IMGAD02.Size           = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 48,62 )
$IMGAD02.Location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 368,100 )
$IMGAD02.Visible        = $FALSE
$ADREPORT.controls.add( $IMGAD02 )
$IMAGEBOXES += $IMGAD02

Function MoveImages
{
    $imgindex = 0
    Foreach ($CB in $CHECKBOXES)
    {
        if ($CB.Checked)
        {
            $IMAGEBOXES[$imgindex].Image = $CB.Tag
            $IMAGEBOXES[$imgindex].Visible = $true
            $imgindex++
        }
    }

    Foreach ($IB in $IMAGEBOXES[($imgindex)..($IMAGEBOXES.Count)])
    {
        $IB.Visible = $false
    }
}

# brings up the SamAccount image when the Username is ticked
$OBJAD01BOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( { MoveImages } )

# Enables the Name image when the name is ticked. 
$OBJAD02BOX.Add_CheckStateChanged( { MoveImages } )

# Launch the checkbox form.
$ADREPORT.Add_Shown( { $ADREPORT.Activate() } )
MoveImages
[void] $ADREPORT.ShowDialog()
```